# Kibana "No results found" when data are in index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have index in Elasticsearch 1.7. + Kibana and index which has this mapping:

```
"logdto": {
    "properties": {
        "filename": {
         "type": "string"
       },
    "message": {
         "type": "string"
       },
    "timestamp": {
         "type": "date",
         "format": "dateOptionalTime"
       }
    }
}
```

When I add this index into Kibana it recognized the index and timestamp field but when I switch to discover it doesn't show any data (while index has plenty of data of course). Time picker is set to last 5 years. Only suspicious I have is on timestamp. Data in this field looks like this:

```
"timestamp": "2017-09-26T15:39:04.798Z"
```

Kibana version is 4.1.8

[image: Discover]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of Kibana are you using? Also can you share the query that Kibana generates based on your settings?

Comment: @Val Kibana version is 4.1.8. I don't know how to get the query. As there are no results there is no button to show request

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your index pattern definition?

Comment: @Val I have added them

Comment: @Michal please screen your discover page

Comment: @JosephMTsai Added

Comment: did your server time correct? it strange

Comment: install sense and check if the ES match all query returns the data. I suspect there may be no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by different time zone on ES server and machine producing the data. Timestamp was greater than time on server running Elasticsearch and Kibana.